# Podgorica-Budva by bus: do I have to buy a ticket in advance?

Tags: public-transport, buses, montenegro

In the end of July I will go (with three other people) by bus from Podgorica to Budva. Do I have to buy a ticket in advance or can I just come to the the bus station a few minutes before the bus departs and hope there will be free places in the bus?

Comment: You can buy it at the bus station - I've never had problems with buses being sold out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many busses between Podgorica and Budva - usually 2-4 busses every hour during the day. They are operated by different operator and I don't know about all of them, but I think that in all of them you can buy a ticket from the driver. And if there is not enough places in the bus- just wait 30 minutes for the next one.